# Como encerrar um software após um certo tempo determinado?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Galera, para ser especifico eu preciso que o meu sistema fique inacessível, após atingir o tempo determinado por mim, porém este tempo não pode ser através da data, eu preciso que cada vez que o software seja inicializado o sistema conte 1, e quando chegar por exemplo a 30(que seria o nº de vezes que foi inicializado) o sistema é encerrado.
Neste sistema não posso pegar dados da internet, nem usar banco de dados.

Comment: É um projeto windows forms?

Comment: Sim, estou usando o visual studio 2008, pq o sistema vai rodar em um aparelho antigo que usa o Windows Mobile 6.1

Comment: Não tem segurança nenhuma de que o seu usuário não vai simplesmente entrar no arquivo txt e alterar o número, mas se você não está se preocupando com isso agora, os programas feitos em windows forms possuem um arquivo de configuração junto ao executável, chamado {nome_do_exe}.exe.config. Ele guarda as configurações que vc definir. Vc pode persistir configurações nele usando `Properties.Settings.Default["utilizacoes"] = 1;`, e ir fazendo a lógica como você preferir.

Comment: ideal acho que seria fazer a contagem pela data pela logica que foi proposta se o usuário abrir e fechar o sistema no mesmo dia as "30 vezes" o sistema será encerrado seria isso? estaria buscando algo como limitação de versão trial?